# Using .NET library from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell snap-in for manipulating a database. The snap-in itself is just a wrapper for the main library implemented in a separate .NET DLL all written in c#.

I have registered both the snap-in and the implementation DLLs with the GAC using installutil.exe

Whilst the snap-in works fine in PowerShell, I need to be able to access the implementation DLL details for things like enums and the like for passing through as arguments to the cmdlets.

Unfortunately, I can't access the contents of the classes inside PowerShell even though the classes are marked as public and everything I'm trying to access is also marked as public.

Do I have to do something special to the implementation DLL in order to make it visible inside PowerShell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Your.Assembly.Name"
```

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 5):

Add-Type will work for PowerShell V2 as described by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846416/using-net-library-from-powershell/1846434#1846434).

You can also use reflection in both V1 and V2 -

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('path to your dll')
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Steven's method to load dll. I prefer to use a var to load it so that you would not see result in output result:

```
 $loadLib = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('path to your dll');
```