# How do I get a list of all tfs alert subscriptions via powershell (get .Net assembly via PowerShell?)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move my tools to powershell, can [this](http://osnabrugge.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/create-tfs-event-subscription-programmatically-with-tfs-api/) be done in PowerShell? the bit I'm really interested in is:

```
IEventService es = tfs.GetService(typeof(IEventService)) as IEventService;
List<Subscription> ls = es.GetAllEventSubscriptions().ToList();
```

Edit: what I really want to do might be using a .NET assembly from powershell and this might then be a duplicate of [Using .NET library from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846416/using-net-library-from-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a TFS API in PowerShell function that I found on a blog long ago that will get you started.  I've posted it to a GitHub Gist.  Basically you ensure you've loaded up the TFS assemblies into the AppDomain and then you can add any TFS Service Interfaces you want to the object and just operate on them just as you would in any c# application, etc.

https://gist.github.com/3288447

Once you have the TFS object returned from the method in the Gist above, you can operate on the loaded services like so:

```
 #use work item service
$tfs = get-tfs $env:TFSSERVERURL -silent
$project = $tfs.wit.Projects | ?{ $_.Name -eq $projectName}
#todo - replace with text for query or file read -- this is deprecated
$query = $project.StoredQueries | ?{ $_.Name -eq 'Active Bugs' }
$queryText = $query.QueryText.Replace("@project","'$projectName'")

$results = $tfs.wit.Query($queryText) 
#do something with the results...
```

In your request above you can just alter the get-tfs method to add your service interface to the set loaded and then operate on the .NET methods much like I do in the example above.